# Convert INT to DATE BIGQUERY

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

I have 2 columns in a big query table that are: month, year ( both as integers), The one digits months are shown as 1,2,3 etc...
I tried to use the DATETIME function and CONCAT to create a new column with both but the following error appears:
DATETIME for argument types: INT64, INT64. Supported signatures: DATETIME(INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64, INT64); DATETIME(DATE, TIME); DATETIME(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATETIME(DATE) at [1:17]

How can I create a column that merges these two and is recognized as a date?

(I tried looking for the solution but no success... :( I'm a completely newbie in this fascinating SQL world)

Thanks!!

Comment: provide sample example of input as well as desired output

Answer (score 0):

If you only have year and month, then add a 1 as a day for a date:

```sql
WITH data AS ( SELECT 2020 y, 10 m)

SELECT DATE(y,m,1)
FROM data
```